# How to type any param with React Typescript in Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-props

I have an existing javascript component:

```
const RenderState = ({ state, else: elseChild = undefined, ...states }) => {
  if (state && states[state]) return states[state]
  if (elseChild) return elseChild
  return null
}

export default RenderState
```

I am trying to convert it to typscript and have so far:

```
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  state: string
  else?: JSX.Element
  any: JSX.Element
}

const RenderState: React.FC<Props> = ({ state, else: elseChild = undefined, ...states }) => {
  if (state && states[state]) return states[state]
  if (elseChild) return elseChild
  return null
}

export default RenderState
```

The problem I am having is of course that `any: JSX.Element` is looking for a prop literally called 'any' when instead I want to allow any prop as a JSX element, such as `custom` in the following example

Here is an example use case of this component:

```
import React from 'react'
import RenderState from './RenderState'

const MyComp = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<string | null>(null)
  <>
    <Button onClick={()=>{setState(null)}}>Default</Button>
    <Button onClick={()=>{setState('custom')}}>Custom</Button>
    <RenderState
      state={state}
      custom={(<p>Some custom content here...</p>)}
      else={(<p>Some default content here...</p>)}
    />
  </>
}
```

Comment: Those seem like bad prop names to me.  Best not to use existing JS/TS keywords as your own...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sonds like you need index signature on your type.
A naive approach would be

```
interface Props {
  state: string
  else?: JSX.Element
  [key: string]: JSX.Element
}
```

However, this won't compile - because index signature on an interface requires that all named properties (`state` and `else`) are compatible with it.

Instead you can rewrite it in a form of type intersection:

```
type Props = {
  state: string
  else?: JSX.Element
} & Record<string, JSX.Element>
```

This still won't compile for the same, but gives us a clue. What if instead of `string` for keys we have a well-known set of possible values?
Next iteration would be

```
type Key = "custom" | "another";

type Props = {
  state: Key | null
  else?: JSX.Element
} & Record<Key, JSX.Element>
```

This looks better. But how do we make it reusable, so that the same component could be used with different lists of possible Keys? Let's make it generic!

**So the final code:**

```
type Props<Key extends string> = {
  state: Key | null
  else?: JSX.Element
} & Record<Key, JSX.Element>
```

You need to make the component a generic function as well:

```
function RenderState<Key>(props: Props<Key>) { ... }
```

And use it in your app:

```
    const [state, setState] = React.useState<"custom" | null>(null);
    <RenderState
      state={state}
      custom={(<p>Some custom content here...</p>)}
      else={(<p>Some default content here...</p>)}
    />
```

**Edit 1**

This approach allows to write `props[props.state]` inside `RenderState` (the result is inferred to `JSX.Element`).
However, it fails to compile with rest destructuring, as in the original code snippet:

```
const {state, else: elseEl, ...rest} = props;
rest[props] // TS error here
```

It reveals a flaw in our type definition. We need to make sure `state` value doesn't include `"state"` and `"else"` literals, to avoid type conflict.

Updated type would be

```
type Props<Key extends string> = {
  state: Exclude<Key, "state" | "else"> | null
  else?: JSX.Element
} & Record<Key, JSX.Element>
```

Now this should compile well

```
const {state, else: elseEl, ...rest} = props;
rest[props]
```

Comment: `function RenderState<Key>(props: Props<Key>) { ... }` would this have to be `Key` and match the above, I am thinking not, but a `<T>` would have the same effect?

Comment: This works with a few tweaks. I had to replace `sates[state]` with `states[state as string]` because the Key was throwing type error: `Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'Pick<Props<Key>, Exclude<Key, "state" | "else">>'`.

Comment: `<T>` would be the same as `<Key>`, correct. It doesn't to have to match `Key` in the generic type definition

Comment: > `states[state as string]`

I edited the type definitiun in the response to be more robust and properly support this scenario without type assertions

Comment: @amakhrov I started a 50pt bounty to give to you as soon as I can. Thank you so much!